# What happens to money paid in fines?

Tags: united-states, fines

Recently, [Facebook agreed to settle a data privacy issue by paying 5 billion dollars](https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2019/07/24/tech/facebook-ftc-settlement/index.html) in the United States, in an action brought by the FTC. What does the government do with all that money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The money goes into the federal government funds, where it gets mixed with all the other sources of income and indistinguishable from money from those sources.

[RedGrittyBrick](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/45753/6259) explains why this money is not much when compared with the USA Federal Budget and most likely will not mean any change of policies. Now there are some possibilities of how this money is incorporated:

- It is incorporated into future budgets. That Facebook has been fined does not mean that tomorrow it will pay $5B. It can ask to do the payments in the future and, if the government agrees with it, when making the budget for the next years there will be already be a line of "Facebook fine --> $X millions" in the income section of the budget. It would not be different from any other expected income.
- If Facebook pays the fine (or part of it) during this fiscal year, that money will be an unexpected income. But since there are usually some expected incomes that fail to materialize, or unexpected expenses that appear, it can be used to compensate for those. Or it could be part of a budget surplus, ready to be used in next year's budget.

  In any case, given how big the USA budget is, and how big uncertainties are (fines like those, but also economic cycles, catastrophes, etc.) it would be very difficult (and pointless) to establish a direct link between this fine and any possible budget surpluss(or a reduction in deficit) at the end of year.

Comment: Funds. Right on then. I cannot upvote because of my low scores here but in all sense of gratitude, thank you for enlightening me.

Answer (score 2):

> Facebook was fined 5 billion dollars

The federal budget is around 3800 billion dollars, federal debt is around 22000 billion dollars.

So this is a fairly tiny amount, comparatively, and perhaps allows federal debt to grow by a tiny tiny bit less than might have been the case otherwise.

Comment: I didn't think it'd be related to the debt... Thanks for that @RedGrittyBrick

Comment: @AnupamDash **It is not related to debt**. It is just money that goes into the government coffers, to be spent as decided by the Congress in the budget. RedGrittyBrick's answer only explains that while that kind of money seems important to you, it is little more than a rounding error when you compare it with the USA budget so it will not affect policy much (no "since we got the money from Facebook then we will no longer collect taxes!" law)

Comment: I'm new to the US economy's debt figure... I'm letting it sink in now

Comment: The relevant comparation is with the budget. Even if USA's debt was 0, that money would not be significative as it is slightly over a 0,01%. If USA's budget was $100 million, then this money would be very significative.